# Windows Store App Certification failing, 6.2.2 uncontrolled access

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am failing to certify my app because of the following certification requirement.

"6.2.2 If your app provides a user with uncontrolled: (i) access to online social networks, or (ii) sharing of personal information with third parties, including other gamers or online acquaintances, then you must assign it a Windows Store rating of at least 12+. For such activity to be considered "controlled", your app must include parental control features that require parental permission to use such sharing features, and you must identify those and explain their functionality in the Notes to testers."

I am using Microsoft's BIng Speech Recognition Control Service (https://inst.platform.bing.com/api/log).  Although I have provided a Privacy Policy and didnt explicitly stated anything regarding age control (should I do so).  Moreover, I am not sure how to include parental control in the app.  Should I just modify the age rating in the Windows Store Dashboard or, should I provide further functionality in the app for a parent to authorize underage usage and if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the age restriction in the app submission form to 12+. You can do it in the Age Rating and rating certificates:
[image]